# Is Quartz 2D in iOS the same as in Mac OS X?

Tags: ios, macos, core-graphics, quartz-2d

Is Quartz programming consistent between iOS and OS X? I'm looking for a good book on Quartz and came across [one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123694736) for Mac OS X but am only building for iOS. Since some APIs are different, such as OpenGL, I'm wondering if the same applies to Quartz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Quartz seems to be very similar, if not identical. Coordinate systems are the same, with the origin in the lower left.

I'm not aware of any differences. [Even bugs are identical.](http://www.openradar.me/11273462)

Comment: But quartz drawing coordinates are 0,0 in the upper right, not lower left?

Comment: @andrewx No, core graphics uses the first quadrant for coordinates, like in math. It's possible, however, to flip the coordinate system by applying a transform. That's what UIKit is doing before calling `drawRect:`.